# Node Js sequelize raw query to sequelize ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, orm, sequelize.js

I need to `sequelize` raw `query` change to `sequelize ORM`

This is my query

```
db.sequelize.query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM cubbersclosure WHERE CAST('"+ fromDate +"' as date) <= toDate AND CAST('"+ toDate +"' as date) >= fromDate", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(closureData=>{
    res.send(closureData);

}).catch(error=>{
    res.status(403).send({status: 'error', resCode:200, msg:'Internal Server Error...!', data:error});
});
```

Change to like this

```
CubbersClosure.findAndCountAll({
    where:{
        // condtion here         
    }
}).then(closureData=>{        
    res.send(closureData);
}).catch(error=>{
    res.status(403).send({status: 'error', resCode:200, msg:'Internal Server Error...!', data:error});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this condition:

```
where: {
  toDate: { $gte: sequelize.cast(req.body.toDate, 'date') },
  fromDate: { $gte: sequelize.cast(req.body.fromDate, 'date') },
},
```

Comment: where i declarer `req.body.fromDate` so can you tell me

Comment: Is this Okay `fromDate: { $lte: sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('toDate'), 'date'),  req.body.fromDate},`

Comment: try to put it instead of `sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('toDate')` and `sequelize.col('fromDate')`, so you should get something like this: `fromDate: { $gte: sequelize.cast(req.body.fromDate, 'date') },`

Comment: can you update your answer. I will give you right tick